# Send array via GET request with AngularJS' $http service

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, angular-http

I need to send a GET request using the `$http` service. One of the parameters will be an array of ids. The url looks like this one **mysite.com/items?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=4**

I tried this approach

```js
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  params: {
    id: ids // ids is [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
)
```

but the url I obain is **mysite.com/items?id=%5B%221%22%2C%222%22%2C%223%22%2C%224%22%5D**

That's Because Angular is converting my value in a JSON string. Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

**[Update]**

I solved the issue thanks to Jonathan's suggestion using jQuery's `$.param()`.

```js
$http(
  method: 'GET'
  url: '/items?' + $.param({id: ids})
)
```

Comment: If you are facing AngularJS specific serialization problem, then httpParamSerializerJQLike is what you need. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852190/angularjs-get-ajax-call-with-array-parameters

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  params: {
    id: JSON.stringify(ids) // ids is [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
)
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine.

Comment: none of these approaches appear to work for me so far with WebApi back end. tried JSON.stringify, 'myvariable[]', going to try a manual string join next

Comment: Neither does it work for me. also have my own Web API backend. Did you get it working @SonicSoul

Comment: This does NOT send a request formatted as asked in the question which is /items?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=4

Answer (score 78):

You can also just do

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  params: {
    "id[]": ids // ids is [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
)
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3121#issuecomment-20453196). Seems simpler.

Comment: I like this method because on the back end (e.g. PHP), the parameter is automatically parsed as an array, avoiding the additional code step of decoding JSON.

Comment: This is the easiest way to communicate with PHP. It's giving the same result as a standard `form` would.

Comment: Best answer yet. 
I'm able to manipulate the `body of the request` on the backend with Node.

Comment: This only worked with my WebApi2 server after I decorated the array parameter like so:

    public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromUri] int[] IDs)

Answer (score 10):

jQuery is great but if your adding jQuery just for this then you could probably do with a non jQuery way and save some precious bytes.

**Non jQuery way :**

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  params: {
    id: ids.toString() //convert array into comma separated values
  }
)
```

On your server convert it back to an array.

Eg. in php

```
$ids = explode(',',Input::get('ids'));

//now you can loop through the data like you would through a regular array. 

foreach($ids as $id)
{
 //do something
}
```

Comment: `ids.toString()` is exactly what I wanted. The other suggestions weren't serializing it into one correct query param in the format I needed: `?id=1,3,4,5`

Comment: @stensrud the question specifically talks about an array of integer ids.

Answer (score 5):

This is valid, just decode it on your backend. Almost all backend languages have a way to decode a URI. If you don't like the way that Angular is serializing it, you can try jquery's $.param().

Comment: I know it is valid, I just wanted to avoid the conversion.

Comment: $.param() should give you a slightly different structure once decoded, more like what you want. You can't not encode URIs, it's not optional. If you don't do it, the browser will.

Comment: Yes you're right with $.param() it is working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use $httpParamSerializer or $httpParamSerializerJQLike

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  data: $httpParamSerializer({'id':[1,2,3,4]}),
})
```

Comment: Unless you're using e.g. CoffeeScript, this is invalid JS. Did you mean to omit the `{}` braces?

Answer (score 1):

[The paramSerializer option can be set to replicate jQuery's serialization method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike):

```
$http({
  url: myUrl,
  method: 'GET',
  params: myParams,
  paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have too many ids, which will cause your request url to be too long depending on your configuration, the following solution will work...

Angular Service:

```
$http.get("website.com/api/items?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3");
```

WebApi Controller

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/items")]
public IEnumerable<Item> Get([FromUri] string[] ids)
{
}
```