# $http GET array of objects from an api

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, airtable

Below is my `AirTableService.js`

```
(function () {
    "use strict";   
    var AirTableService = function ($http, $q) {
        var AirTableMethods = {
            getMyRounds: function(AirTable_secret){
                var deferObject_myRounds;
                var myRounds_promise = $http.get('https://api.airtable.com/v0/XXXXXXX/Rounds?view=Main%20View&maxRecords=10&callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {
                    headers : {
                        'Authorization' : AirTable_secret.apikey,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }
                });
                deferObject_myRounds = deferObject_myRounds || $q.defer();

                myRounds_promise.then(function(data){
                    deferObject_myRounds.resolve(data);
                });                
                return deferObject_myRounds.promise;
            }
        };
        return AirTableMethods;
    };

    AirTableService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

    angular.module('appGolf')
      .service('AirTableService', AirTableService);

}());
```

In there as you can see, using [AirTable](http://airtable.com)'s `api` I am trying to `GET` data from my table. I'm passing the parameters `view` and `maxRecords` and it works. 
Documentation states I can pass `sort`,

[image]

which I then changed to,

```
https://api.airtable.com/v0/XXXXXXX/Rounds?view=Main%20View&maxRecords=10&sort=[{field:'RoundID',direction:'desc'}]&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

and clearly that doesn't work and it it gives me this error, 
[image]
I know this is because `sort` is a `array of objects` and I know how I am passing this is incorrect.

My question is, how do you do this in `AngularJS`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send array via GET request with AngularJS' $http service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957858/send-array-via-get-request-with-angularjs-http-service)

Comment: have you tried double quotes like the example shows?

Comment: `$http` already returns a promise.  You don't have to use `$q`.

Comment: @DrewJordan I just tried, no difference, same error

Comment: your error message shows an extra single quote after 'desc', you didn't add that by mistake, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855395/789782)
As mentioned there, I needed to add,

```
paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
```

And if you are interested, my function now looks like,

```
var myRounds_promise = $http.get('https://api.airtable.com/v0/XXXXX/Rounds?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {
                params: {
                    view: 'Main View',       
                    maxRecords: 10,
                    sort: [{"field": 'RoundID', "direction":'desc'}]                        
                },
                paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',                    
                headers : {
                    'Authorization' : AirTable_secret.apikey,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            });
```

Thanks everyone for their suggestions and helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your service is very verbose and hard to read.  I would write it like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ /* dependencies */ ]);

app.factory("AirTableService", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        getMyRounds: function(AirTable_secret) {
            return $http.get('path/to/API', {
                //put your sorting JSON object here in params
                params: { sort: [{field: "RoundID", direction: "desc"}] },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization' : AirTable_secret.apikey,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            });
        },
        anotherMethod: function() {
            //etc....
        },
        yetAnotherMethod: function() {
            return $http.post(); //maybe POST something
        }
    };
}]);
```

Inject it to your controller and use:

```
AirTableService.getMyRounds(airtableSecret).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but still getting the same error. BTW appreciate formatting my service, it makes sense.